# Can I declare a non-global variable to store asynchronous values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

I have multiple JavaScript files.
I have a JS function that runs upon load that contains multiple AJAX calls.
Each AJAX call performs a callback (as well as increments a synchronous counter)::
`myArray.push('somevalue');`

so that I can verify when all AJAX calls (for this JS file) have finished.

Is there a way that I can get away with not declaring myArray as a global variable, while allowing asynchronous callbacks to push into this array?

Comment: You would have to pass `myArray` to each call.

Comment: If you pass myArray to each call, it will still reference that variable?  Since JS does pass-by-value, the asynchronous call won't be searching for the [reference of] original variable?

Comment: Just create a scope that isn't global, jQuery document.ready or an IIFE would do that, and set the array in the same or a higher scope than the ajax calls.

Comment: If you pass an array, then the *value* is a *reference to the array*.

Comment: you have 2 good solutions in comments here , but my question, why are you concerned about making this array global?

Comment: @ScottSelby I don't want to worry about me or someone else accidentally overwriting a global array since the global would be shared across multiple files (the project is actually much more complex than this).

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, thanks.  I forgot about that since I was trying to generalize to any variable.  To confirm, the variable would continue to exist even once the function finishes (since that's usually when a variable's scope ends) if the asynchronous calls last longer than the function wrapping them?

Comment: @user3727206: Yes, it would. The callback function just needs to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute some code after a set number of AJAX requests have completed, use `$.when`.

If you are using `myArray` solely to know when the requests are finished, you can remove it. If you are using it to store the result of each request, you can keep it in the same scope as the requests and then access it in the `done` handler. Try this:

```
var myArray = [];

var ajax1 = $.ajax({
    url: '/foo/',
    success: function(data) {
        myArray.push(data);
    });
});

var ajax2 = $.ajax({
    url: '/bar/',
    success: function(data) {
        myArray.push(data);
    });
});

$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function() {
    // both requests complete
    // myArray will contain the data of both requests at this point...
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(myArray[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I wasn't the down voter , but I think it's because you didn't address the situation OP asked about, if he can have an array not be global , and have each call back assign to it.

Comment: This does address that - if the sole purpose of the array is to know when the requests have finished, then the array is no longer required. If it's used to store the result of each request, it can be in the same scope as the requests themselves (ie. not global) and then accessed in the `done` handler.

Comment: I'd explain that , and upvote for a better solution , I just learned of .when() a couple months ago and cleaned up so much code with it

Comment: @ScottSelby yeah, it's a really handy method for reigning in a AJAX heavy site. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately, my jQuery version is a bit behind, but I'm currently considering upgrading.

Comment: @user3727206 it's definitely worth it. What version are you using?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 1.2... but I need a workaround in case the upgrade doesn't go smoothly.

Comment: Holy wow, that's nearly *7 years out of date*. I would imagine there will be some work involved in upgrading that but you really, really need to. It will be *much* faster upgrading to 1.11.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable that is only accessible within the scope you want it (e.g., inside the function).

Something like:

```
var ajaxCalls = function() {
    var myArray = [];

    var ajax1 = $.ajax({
        url: 'foo.com',
        success: function(data) {
            myArray.push(data);
        });
    });

    // do more AJAX stuff

    $.when(ajax1, ..., ).done(function() {
        // make sure all requests are complete
        // do stuff with the completed array
    });
};
```

Since JavaScript has functional scoping, your myArray variable won't be global, but it will be accessible within the ajax callbacks. Hope that helps!